# How can $all use a multi-key index?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to understand how the $all operator can make use of a multi-key index.

[Mongo documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) says that an index on an array:

> results in the database indexing each element of the array

So if I have two documents with embedded arrays [a b c d] and [b c] I believe the resulting index will look like this:

```
a
b
b
c
c
d
```

Now suppose I issue a query for $all [b c], I expect both documents to match. But how is the above index any use at all for finding these documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens with a query like $all [b,c] is that the index is used to find the documents containing "b", then all those documents are checked to see if they also contain "c".  The index is somewhat helpful in that it narrows down the number of documents that need to be checked.  But in some cases the query still could take awhile.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm what @matulef says, and can advise therefore to order your parameters so that the *least frequent* value is first in the $all array. This minimizes the number of objects that Mongo needs to scan to check that the other $all values are also present.